# Platform For Volunteer Management Website

Tags: plugins, web

I help out at a local soup kitchen, and they are wanting to create a website.  Most of their criteria are pretty simple, they want to be able to have a calendar, post pictures, and have a blog.  However they also want to be able to manage volunteer's.  They want to be able to post a event, have a list of jobs that they need volunteer's for that event, and allow people to sign up for the jobs.  I would like to base this website on a well known platform like DotNetNuke, WordPress, or Drupal.  Before I go and code my own plugin for managing volunteers I decided to see if I could find a platform that already has a module available.  So far I have not been able to find anything.  Has anybody heard of one or used one in the past?  I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a whole range of ways to do this, but I haven't ever seen a dedicated solution (plugin or otherwise).

On the one hand, a blog could do all that you're asking. Posting pictures and blog entries? That's wordpress all over. Want a calendar? We have [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/calendar/) for that. Want to let volunteers sign up for stuff? Let them post comments.

On the other hand, the problem you're describing isn't unique: In my own experience I've wanted the software you describe. May I suggest that, if you have the time, you make something totally awesome for the volunteer community?

Comment: These are all good suggestions, but they want something that is very user friendly.  They want to be able to have a quick view of what is needed and what needs are filled.  They are currently using volunteerspot.com.  It works pretty well, but they are having a couple issues, and they want the functionality embedded in their website.  I agree with you, if I cannot find a existing plugin then I am hoping to create one for the community.

Answer (score 0):

Our company, Wired Impact, recently released a plugin called Wired Impact Volunteer Management that provides exactly the functionality you're looking for. You can learn more and download the plugin at https://wordpress.org/plugins/wired-impact-volunteer-management/.